# How to remove duplicate rows from the dataset, which include the duplicate dictionary as well?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

So I have the following dataset.

```
data = [[1, 'abc', 25, 'V', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc',25, 'V', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc', 25, 'MV', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc', 25, 'V', {'DEBUG': '1', 'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'MODULE_NAME': 'iosc_xtal32m', 'TEST': 'xtal32m', 'CS': 'bb', 'XTAL32M_53X_OSC.VI': 1}]] 
Dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =  ['Chip_Number', 'Test_Key', 'Temp', 'Test_Data_Unit', 'Test_Label'] )
Dataframe
```

In my dataset, the last column "Test_Label" include the dictionary in **each** row.

I want to remove the duplicate rows (appeared first) from my dataset based on the column "Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit" and "Test_Label".

I use following code to remove the first appeared duplicates in my dataset. However, I'm getting an error.

```
#Drop the duplicates from the column of Dataframe["Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit"] and only keep the last one
Dataframe.duplicated(subset = ["Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit","Test_Label"]).sum()
Dataframe.loc[Dataframe.duplicated(subset = ["Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit","Test_Label"], keep='last'),:]
Dataframe = Dataframe.drop_duplicates(subset = ["Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit","Test_Label"],keep='last')

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 10000)
Dataframe
```

The error, I'm getting after running the above code.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

However, when I using the same code above without using the **"Test_Label"** column. it works fine. But, That is not my intention.

Can someone have an idea, How can I improve the above code?

My dataset should look like this after removing the duplicate rows?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is convert the column with `dict` values to string. But dictionary is unordered data type, so we need to sort it first:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'abc', 25, 'V', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc',25, 'V', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc', 25, 'MV', {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'TEST': 'ldo_xtal', 'CS': 'bb', 'MODULE_NAME': 'ildo_xtal'}], [1, 'abc', 25, 'V', {'DEBUG': '1', 'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MODE': 'buck', 'MODULE_NAME': 'iosc_xtal32m', 'TEST': 'xtal32m', 'CS': 'bb', 'XTAL32M_53X_OSC.VI': 1}]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =  ['Chip_Number', 'Test_Key', 'Temp', 'Test_Data_Unit', 'Test_Label'] )

# create temporary column with string from the dict column `Test_Label`
df['tmp'] = df['Test_Label'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, sorted(x.items()) )))

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["Chip_Number","Test_Key","Temp","Test_Data_Unit","tmp"], keep='last')

del df['tmp'] # delete temporary column

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Chip_Number Test_Key  Temp Test_Data_Unit                                         Test_Label
1            1      abc    25              V  {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MOD...
2            1      abc    25             MV  {'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.000', 'POWER_MOD...
3            1      abc    25              V  {'DEBUG': '1', 'REVISION': 'ac', 'VBAT': '3.00...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrej Kesely. This is really helpful. Also, I learn something new. Thanks again. :D